# Firefox doesn't adhere to preserveAspectRatio

Tags: html, svg

I have the following graphic embedded into markup:

```
<div id="svgContainer" >
  <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet"
        viewBox="0 0 1800 1111">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="00%" x2 ="0" y2="100%">
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="0"/>
        <stop stop-color="white" offset="1"/>
      </linearGradient>

      <mask id="masking" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <rect y="0.3" width="1" height=".7" fill="url(#gradient)" />
        <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".5" fill="white" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%" 
    id="coverImageContainer" mask="url(#masking)">
      <img id="coverImage" src="/images/v3/eminem-cover.jpg" />
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
</div>
```

On Safari and Chrome, the graphic resizes appropriately using the center of the graphic as the appropriate anchor point. On Firefox, however, the image resizes as thought I had set `preserveAspectRatio` on the `svg` element to `xMinYMax meet`. Any ideas what's causing this discrepency in behavior?

Comment: What CSS are you using to size the SVG?  As it is, Firefox makes the SVG dimensions match the aspect ratio ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hmRn/1/)), so you can't really tell the effect of `xMaxYMin`...

Comment: And when I force the SVG aspect ratio to be different from the viewBox ratio, I'm getting proper behaviour for `xMaxYMin meet` (the image is to the top/right of the SVG area) in Firefox 27 for Windows.  http://jsfiddle.net/2hmRn/2/

Comment: You may want to add explicit dimensions to the SVG element. Firefox seems to like that.